# I'm getting error when I trying load css in reactjs

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to load css into my subpage, but reactjs reported an error like this, it confuses me, please help me, thank you very much ...

> Failed to compile.
>
> ./src/css/style1.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-3-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./src/css/style1.css)
> Module not found: Can't resolve './0' in 'C:\Users\hokag\Desktop\Fisrt.ProJ\run-app\src\css'

Comment: not enough information. Show the piece of react code where you import the stylesheet into the 'subpage'. (component? - have you exported the component properly?)

Comment: As per my understanding the try to provide relative file path.
If you can provide more information, it will definitely help to debug.

Comment: It sounds like that file doesn't exist.

Comment: Sorry everyone, I successfully fixed the error, I found each css code, this is the code that caused me trouble ..

Comment: Do you know why ?

Comment: ![Valid XHTML](https://scontent.fdad6-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/61386108_372380950067509_5519912996979081216_n.png?_nc_cat=108&_nc_ht=scontent.fdad6-1.fna&oh=3a413d3200662011cf7db9d4a908491b&oe=5D567ACC).